# iOS Framework headers not found in some files of the framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-frameworks

I am developing a framework for my obj-c iOS app.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

My framework files builds correctly and I can import it into my sample project and it builds correctly. But my project doesn't perform as expected.

When I did deeper into my framework headers, I find my problem.

Certain header files allow me to CMD-Click on the imports to view the corresponding header files in my project.

So for example:

1. In *TestFile.h*, I have: `#import <Framework/SomeFile.h>`, I can CMD-Click on this grand and I get linked to `SomeFile.h`
2. In *TestFile2.h*, I also have: `#import <Framework/SomeFile.h>`. When I CMD-Click on this, I get the `Question Mark` symbol indicating that the file isn't found.

In my Framework Project, I have a directory structure like so:

```
FrameworkProj.xcodeproj
->FrameworkProj
  ->FrameworkHeaders.h
  ->Folder
    ->some files
    ->some folders
  ->Folder
```

I'm wondering if I haven't set a flag in my Build Settings that doesn't recursively link the files to my compiled framework, but I'm wondering why can I see the files in my headers files if this is the case.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May seem stupid but I solved this problem with a single line.

I needed to include `-all_load` in `Target > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags`

Comment: where did u find this solution?

Comment: It was a suggestion from one of many threads I was reading at the time. Unable to link directly unfortunately